# Block that grows to fit its children and is horizontally centered

Tags: css

Hoping that this is not a duplicate of one of the many other "centered div" questions...

I'm looking for a way to convert a table-based page layout to clean CSS. The existing design has a table with a single cell in a single row, and all the rest of the page content is inside that cell. The table is centered with `margin-left` and `margin-right` set to `auto`.

There are many many pages using this layout. Most of them have the same width, so as you move from page to page within the site, the big table container stays in the same place horizontally.

Occasionally there's a page with wider content. The table grows to allow its children to fit, and remains properly centered (the left and right edges move outward by the same amount).

I'm unable to find any way to replicate this behavior without a table. I can change the `<table><tr><td>...</td></tr></table>` to a `<div style="display:table">...</div>` but that doesn't feel like a correct solution. After we've been told for so long to stop using tables for layout, can it be that there is still no alternative?

Here's a snippet that shows what I'm talking about. There are 2 centered blocks, identical except that one of them has `display:table`. When you press the button below a block, it cycles through 3 children. One that's too big, one that's too small, and one that's capable of fitting the container exactly (the container's width is between the child's `min-width` and `max-width`). When the big child is displayed, the table container still looks nice and the other one has an ugly overflow.

Note: For a solution to be useful, it must not require manual calculation of margins. I am looking for a *general* solution that will work for arbitrary dynamically-generated content inside the container, not just the 3 simple blocks in the snippet.

```js
var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
for(var i = 0; i < containers.length; ++i) {
  (function() {
    var c = containers[i],
        b = c.nextElementSibling;
    b.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
      big = c.querySelector(".bigchild");
      medium = c.querySelector(".mediumchild");
      small = c.querySelector(".smallchild");
      if(big.style.display != "block" &&
         medium.style.display != "block" &&
         small.style.display != "block") {
        big.style.display = "block";
      } else if(big.style.display == "block") {
        big.style.display = "none";
        medium.style.display = "block";
      } else if(medium.style.display == "block") {
        medium.style.display = "none";
        small.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        small.style.display = "none";
      }
    });
  })();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.bigchild {
  background-color: #9ff;
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 700px;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}
.mediumchild {
  background-color: #6f6;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}
.smallchild {
  background-color: #fcc;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto 20px;
}
#container1 {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container" id="container1">
    <div class="bigchild">big</div>
    <div class="mediumchild">medium</div>
    <div class="smallchild">small</div>
  </div>
  <button>Next</button>

  <div class="container" id="container2">
    <div class="bigchild">big</div>
    <div class="mediumchild">medium</div>
    <div class="smallchild">small</div>
  </div>
  <button>Next</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `min-width` and `min-height` of the container instead of the `width` and `height`. If you explicitly set the these dimensions, the container element is not allowed to grow to accommodate its children.

The `display` attribute also needs to change to `inline-block` so it will fit to the width of the children.

The last thing that needs to be done, to preserve the centering is to set the container's parent to `text-align:center` (this will necessitate setting `text-align:left` in the container). This also removes the need to set the container's `margin`s to auto. In my snippet, I applied this text-align to the body but you can just use a wrapping div instead if this causes issues with the rest of your layout.

```js
var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
for(var i = 0; i < containers.length; ++i) {
  (function() {
    var c = containers[i],
        b = c.nextElementSibling;
    b.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
      big = c.querySelector(".bigchild");
      medium = c.querySelector(".mediumchild");
      small = c.querySelector(".smallchild");
      if(big.style.display != "block" &&
         medium.style.display != "block" &&
         small.style.display != "block") {
        big.style.display = "block";
      } else if(big.style.display == "block") {
        big.style.display = "none";
        medium.style.display = "block";
      } else if(medium.style.display == "block") {
        medium.style.display = "none";
        small.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        small.style.display = "none";
      }
    });
  })();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align:center;
}
.container {
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 400px;
  min-height: 250px;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:left;
}
.bigchild {
  background-color: #9ff;
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 700px;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}
.mediumchild {
  background-color: #6f6;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}
.smallchild {
  background-color: #fcc;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bigchild">big</div>
  <div class="mediumchild">medium</div>
  <div class="smallchild">small</div>
</div>
<button>Next</button>
```

Comment: This does handle the 3 boxes in the snippet correctly. I have a new problem caused by the use of `min-width`, but I'll make that a separate question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26914693/2404501 if you're interested in the followup question