# min-width isn't preferred strongly enough when child is a table

Tags: css, css-tables

My previous question got an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26912932/2404501) using `min-width` to set the width of a containing block but allow it to grow when its children are too big.

This worked fine with some kinds of children (simple divs with their own `min-width` and `max-width` specified explicitly). Now I'm looking at a more complex variation in which the children are tables. (Legitimate tables with semantically meaningful rows and columns, not page-layout tables.)

There is no manually-specified `min-width` or `max-width` on these tables, but tables have an inherent maximum and minimum width, corresponding to the width that the table would have if rendered with no line breaks in any of the cells (maximum) and the width that it would have with line breaks inserted insertion of all possible line breaks (minimum).

In the existing page layout which I'm trying to replace, the outermost container is a table (the bad kind of table) with a single cell in a single row, and a CSS `width` (not `min-width`) set to the preferred width. When the children are tables, they try really hard to fit into the container's width. A wide table will be rendered with line breaks to make it fit, and the container will expand only if the child *still* doesn't fit after all line breaks are inserted.

In other words, the parent's `width` property is treated as a minimum, but it is also a strongly *preferred* width, which has a higher priority than the child's preferred (i.e. maximum) width.

By contrast, when the parent is a plain div with `display:inline-block` and a specified `min-width`, the parent's `min-width` is not strongly preferred. The child prefers to be wider, so the parent expands, even if the child is *capable* of being rendered with a smaller width.

Here's a snippet, much like the one in the previous question, which demonstrates all of this. The goal is to make the second container act like the first one in some way that is more "proper" than using `display:table` for layout.

(Note: the table widths at the heart of this question are very sensitive to choice of font. I hope the Courier New comes through and everybody sees the same widths in the snippet.)

```js
var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
for(var i = 0; i < containers.length; ++i) {
  (function() {
    var c = containers[i],
        b = c.nextElementSibling;
    b.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
      big = c.querySelector(".bigchild");
      medium = c.querySelector(".mediumchild");
      small = c.querySelector(".smallchild");
      if(big.style.display != "block" &&
         medium.style.display != "block" &&
         small.style.display != "block") {
        big.style.display = "block";
      } else if(big.style.display == "block") {
        big.style.display = "none";
        medium.style.display = "block";
      } else if(medium.style.display == "block") {
        medium.style.display = "none";
        small.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        small.style.display = "none";
      }
    });
  })();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Courier New";
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
.container {
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 250px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.bigchild, .mediumchild, .smallchild {
  display: none;
}
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto 20px;
}
#container1 {
  display: table;
  width: 400px;
}
#container2 {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container1">
    <table class="bigchild">
      <tr>
        <td>Lots of</td>
        <td>columns</td>
        <td>make this</td>
        <td>a very</td>
        <td>wide</td>
        <td>table</td>
        <td>that won't</td>
        <td>fit</td>
        <td>even with</td>
        <td>added</td>
        <td>line breaks</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="mediumchild">
      <tr>
        <td>This table</td>
        <td>is smaller</td>
        <td>and</td>
        <td>it fits</td>
        <td>but</td>
        <td>only with</td>
        <td>added</td>
        <td>line breaks</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="smallchild">
      <tr>
        <td>very</td>
        <td>small</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button>Next</button>

  <div class="container" id="container2">
    <table class="bigchild">
      <tr>
        <td>Lots of</td>
        <td>columns</td>
        <td>make this</td>
        <td>a very</td>
        <td>wide</td>
        <td>table</td>
        <td>that won't</td>
        <td>fit</td>
        <td>even with</td>
        <td>added</td>
        <td>line breaks</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="mediumchild">
      <tr>
        <td>This table</td>
        <td>is smaller</td>
        <td>and</td>
        <td>it fits</td>
        <td>but</td>
        <td>only with</td>
        <td>added</td>
        <td>line breaks</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="smallchild">
      <tr>
        <td>very</td>
        <td>small</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button>Next</button>
```

Comment: I see a workaround for your problem as it appears in your snippet. The javascipt is setting the `display` property for the tables to `block`, changing this to `display:table` and adding a `max-width` to the table the same value as the `min-width` of the container would create the effect you are after. I don't consider this a full answer as it involves duplication of information.

Comment: Of course those `"block"`s in the script should be `"table"`. I just forgot to change them when I changed the original child divs to tables. The `max-width` idea works, but in the general case where the children may or may not be tables, forcing them all to `display:table` means we haven't solved the problem of abusing tables for layout.

Comment: According to your question, the children are tables in this scenario. Is this not the case?

Comment: Yes, but that's because I'm trying to follow the stackoverflow policy of making questions as specific as possible and using [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show the issue. When I had a problem that didn't depend on the type of the child nodes, I made them divs to keep it simple. Then when I had a problem with child nodes that were tables, I started a separate question for those. But the actual goal is and always was a solution that works for *arbitrary content*.

Comment: I am trying to clarify what is your intended behavior in the grand scheme. Does the answer to your first question work when the objects are not tables? Are the objects being shown and hidden via javascript similar to your snippet or does their display property remain at one value?

Comment: The javascript snippet just shows you 3 different versions of the demo sequentially. I thought this would be helpful in understanding the question, but the script doesn't have anything to do with the problem I'm asking about. You could remove the script and make 3 copies of the container, each with one child, and the layout issue would be the same. And the real problem is that I don't have 3 different things I need to put in that container. I have hundreds. And more being created all the time. It needs to be a *generic* solution that I can put anything into.

Comment: Would it be possible, then, to just write a css rule that only targets the tables, such as: `.container > table { display:table; }`?

Comment: It works, but again it's just taking care of a special case. What if the container has a table as a grandchild? And what about padding, border, and margins? An `inline-table` with siblings? The problem's getting harder the more I think about it.

Comment: "The goal is to make the second container act like the first one in some way that is more "proper" than using display:table for layout" - what is wrong with `display: table`? It's perfectly acceptable to use elements with `display: table` for layout :)

Comment: putting a white-space:nowrap on the first container yields result like the second container. However putting white-space:normal on second container does not give the same result as the first container.

    #container1 {
        display: table;
        width: 400px;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }

Answer (score 0):

I think `.container {min-width: 400px;width: min-content;}`, modulo vendor prefixes, is what you want.